# See which part of a stylesheet is applied to particular widget

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I use a global stylesheet (`qss`) with my Qt application. Is there a way to see which style is applied to a particular element (widget)? I can use trial and error, but it would be much easier if I could just see which style is used / applied.

The `styleSheet` property of the widgets themselves is empty. Is there a way to debug which style from the stylesheet is exactly applied?

Answer (score 1):

You can get only stylesheets that you applied by yourself. Qt doesn't operate stylesheets. It use `QStyle` + `QPalette` for customization. So you may look through code and understand how widgets are painted.